# Why do partitions require nested selects?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a page to show 10 messages by each user (don't ask me why)
I have the following code:

`SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by user_id) as row_num

FROM "posts"

WHERE row_num <= 10`

It doesn't work.

When I do this:

`SELECT *

FROM (

  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by user_id) as row_num FROM "posts") as T

WHERE row_num <= 10`

It does work.
Why do I need nested query to see `row_num` column? Btw, in first request I actually see it in results but can't use `where` keyword for this column.

Comment: Clarify "doesn't work". Any error messages? Could it just be that you cannot use a column alias in the where clause (not sure if Postgresql allows that)?

Comment: Seems Postgres is similar to Oracle in this respect: you can't reference the column by the alias name, just the expression itself... Just guessing as I don't have PG experience, but I'd try doning this: `SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by user_id) as row_num
 FROM "posts"
 WHERE (row_number() over(partition by user_id)) <= 10` Howeevr this syntax seems very odd, and I feel that it might not be supported...

Comment: `row_num` is not a column in `posts` but, is a column in your sub query `T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be the same "rule" as any query, column aliases aren't visible to the `WHERE` clause;

This will also fail;

```
SELECT id AS newid
FROM test
WHERE newid=1;     -- must use "id" in WHERE clause
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE <condition>
```

will execute in next order:

```
3.SELECT *
1.FROM table
2.WHERE <condition>
```

so, as Joachim Isaksson say, columns in `SELECt` clause are not visible in `WHERE` clause, because of processing order.

In your second query, column `row_num` are fetched in `FROM` clause first, so it will be visible in `WHERE` clause.

[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/) is simple list of steps in order they executes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason for this rule in standard SQL.

Consider the statement:

```
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by user_id) as row_num
FROM "posts"
WHERE row_num <= 10 and p.type = 'xxx';
```

When does the `p.type = 'xxx'` get evaluated relative to the row number?  In other words, would this return the first ten rows of "xxx"?  Or would it return the "xxx"s in the first ten rows?

The designers of the SQL language recognize that this is a hard problem to resolve.  Only allowing them in the `select` clause resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19762/why-is-the-select-clause-listed-first) and [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in) on dba.stockexchange.com about order in which SQL executes SELECT clause. I think it aplies not only for PostgreSQL, but for all RDBMS.